# Extension of a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

Well, for (a) I have no idea how to extend, I feel that there will be a continuous extension. For example I can define $f=g$ when $f$ takes values from upper boundary of the disk and upper half plane and same way for lower boundary and lower half plane.
For (b) I have no idea.

(c) is true by Uryshon's lemma? As the plane is normal, and the given sets are closed and disjoint.

Comment: For (a), just define $f(x) = g(\frac{x}{\|x\|})$, for $x \notin B$. For (b),(c), it is simpler to look at functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (a) you can use [Tietze's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem):

$B$ is a closed subset of a normal space.

For (b) I think you could take any function with a discontinuity at distance one from the origin (like for example $\frac{1}{1 - |x^2 + y^2|}$)

For (c) your answer is correct: the first set is a circle around $0$ of radius $1.5$, the second set is the closed unit disk union the complement of an open disk of radius $2$ so that we have two closed disjoint sets and can apply Urysohn.